# Angular - How can i transform an Object into an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I'm working on a line chart of ChartJS library.
I have this object and I would like to transform it in an array, because I want to use its data on it.
Searching on the net I found that map it's the easiest way to do that but I can't actually use it on Object, but only on arrays. How can i convert it in an array or simply use the json data on the line chart? That's the json object i have right now.

```
{labels: Array(2), values: Array(2)}
labels: (2) ["sales-be", "sales-mw"]
values: (2) [48, 8]
```

i tried like this but it gives me errors:

```
var labels = this.errorsList.map(function (e) {
      return e.labels;
    });

    var datas = this.errorsList.map(function (e) {
      return e.values;
    });
```

TypeError: this.errorsList.map is not a function

Comment: So you want labels array holds strings and values array holds integers?

Comment: Can you post `errorsList`?

Comment: Can you update your question with the expected array structure

Comment: The properties are already arrays. You could access them directly `var labels = this.errorsList.labels` and `var datas = this.errorsList.values`.

Comment: If I understand correctly `errorsList` is an object, and map is not an object enumerable, you can use a  for..in loop to iterate thru an object. Tho as the other commentators pointed out the values appear to be arrays, so you can access them directly thru dot notation with out having to perform any other operations.

Answer (score 0):

The properties are already arrays. So you could access them directly.

Try the following

```js
export class AppComponent {
  errorsList = {
    labels: ["sales-be", "sales-mw"],
    values: [48, 8]
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chartData = [{
      data: this.errorsList.values,
      label: 'Sales',
      fill: false
    }];

    this.chartLabels = this.errorsList.labels;

    this.chartColors = [{
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 15, 15, 1)'
    }];
  };
}
```

Template

```html
<div id="chart-container">
    <canvas #myCanvas id="canvas" baseChart [chartType]="chartType" [datasets]="chartData" [labels]="chartLabels" [colors]="chartColors" [options]="chartOptions"></canvas>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/line-chart-nxzvoo)

Here the `errorsList` is defined with hard values **only** for illustration. You don't have to define it in your code.

Again this code is an example and it's only here to illustrate how to use the properties from your object, nothing more.